# Decompile a DLL file from Microsoft Media Creation Tool

Tags: dll, decompile

In this Superuser topic [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool, how does it work?](https://superuser.com/questions/1220373/), it is possible to extract the URL from SetupMgr.dll. My question is, how do I extract this URL from SetupMgr.dll? I want to be able to do this in future versions of the Media Creation Tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The following links are for Fall Creators Update and may be change in future updates.

Download the Media Creation Tool from [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/windows10). Open the executable in [7ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and extract all the files in a folder. Then download [Strings from Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) and place it in that previous folder whre you've extracted files. Open Command Prompt in that folder and run this command:

```
For /R %X in (*.*) do (Strings.exe %X) | find /i "LinkID"
```

This command searches all the strings in all files recursively and shows the strings containing "LinkID" (piped to `find /i`). Open all the URLs in any browser and one of them (total 7 or 8 links) will download the Products.CAB or Products.XML file which contains *all Windows ESD download links*.

Alternatively, extract the **SetupMgr.dll** file from MediaCreationTool.exe as above. Then open that DLL in IDA. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to open strings window and find `LinkID`. There will be two strings.

[image: LinkID_in_IDA]

- The Link for Products.CAB: **https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=841361**
- This LinkID redirected to another direct download link (**may not work in future**):

  - [products_20170317.cab](https://wscont.apps.microsoft.com/winstore/OSUpgradeNotification/MediaCreationTool/prod/Products_20170317.cab)
  - [products_20171005.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/9/38926395-6FB1-4487-83DF-4241D2EA79F7/products_20171005.cab)
  - [products_20180105.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/3/323D0F94-95D2-47DE-BB83-1D4AC3331190/products_20180105.cab)
  - [products_20180420.cab](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/6/626729CF-8C1C-43DF-8C9C-AD2FD56948C3/products_20180420.cab)

**Tip:** Check the real file type of MediaCreaTool.exe using the following [7ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) command and that will be CAB type.

```
7z t MediaCreationTool.exe | find /i "type"
```

Comment: For those wondering why a simple `grep` or `findstr` doesn't find this, it's because it's UTF-16.